# How to use ReactDOM.createPortal() in React 16?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using React 16 and need portals, but am not able to find any documentation on this feature. Does anyone know how to use this yet?

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/10675

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/portals.html

Comment: The docs very clearly explain how to use them... did you read them?

Comment: @ndugger Yeah, Docs are good enough now :). But OP asked the question 2 days ago. React v16 was not released then. It was released today and docs were also made available today.

Comment: @HardikModha Good, then we can remove this question that is no longer needed.

Comment: I'd say, let this question be there since the answer by @HardikModha emphasises on the important part that can be ignored while reading the docs.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

React v16 has just released a couple of hours ago (Yay!!) which officially supports [`Portal`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/portals.html).

**What is Portal? Since How long has it been there?**

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

`Portal` is not new concept in the react community. Many libraries are available that supports this kind of functionality. e.g [react-portal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-portal) and [react-gateway](https://github.com/cloudflare/react-gateway).

**What happens when rendering any react app?**

Generally, when rendering any React application, a single DOM element is used to render the whole React tree.

```
class HelloReact extends React.Component {
   render() {
       return (
          <h1>Hello React</h1>
       );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloReact />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As you can see we are rendering our react component into a DOM element having id `root`.

**What is Portal and why is it needed? Why is it there?**

Portals are a way to render React children outside the main DOM hierarchy of the parent component ***without losing the react context***. I'm emphasizing on it because very popular libraries like [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) heavily uses the react context. So context availability when using `Portal` is very helpful.

As per the [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/portals.html) docs,

> A typical use case for portals is when a parent component has an overflow: hidden or z-index style, but you need the child to visually "break out" of its container. For example, dialogs, hovercards, and tooltip.

So, with portals, you can render a parallel react tree onto another DOM node when needed. Even though it is rendered in the different DOM node,  parent component can catch the uncaught events. See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/acdlite/pen/MEJEVV) provided in the docs itself.

The below example should give your more idea:

```
// index.html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <div id="another-root"></div>
    </body>
</html>

// index.jsx
const mainContainer = document.getElementById('root');
const portalContainer = document.getElementById('another-root');

class HelloFromPortal extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return (
           <h1>I am rendered through a Portal.</h1>
         );
    }
}

class HelloReact extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                 <h1>Hello World</h1>
                 { ReactDOM.createPortal(<HelloFromPortal />, portalContainer) }
             </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloReact />, mainContainer);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/62rvxkonnw

You can use devtools inspect element and see that `<h1>I am rendered through a Portal.</h1>` is rendered inside `#another-root` tag, whereas `<h1>Hello World</h1>` is rendered inside `#root` tag.

Hope this helps :)

**Update**: To answer [@PhillipMunin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393642/how-to-use-reactdom-createportal-in-react-16/46435051#comment80738684_46435051).

> What is the different between `ReactDOM.render` and
>   `ReactDOM.createPortal`?

1. Even though the component rendered through the portal is rendered somewhere else (Outside the current container root), it remains present as the child of the same parent component. (Who invoked the `ReactDOM.createPortal`) So any events on the child are propagated to the parent. (Ofc, This doesn't work if you manually stop the propagation of the event.)
2. Same context is accessible inside the component rendered through a portal. But not in the case when we do `ReactDOM.render` directly.

I've created another demo to illustrate my point. https://codesandbox.io/s/42x771ykwx

Comment: How is that different from writing `{ ReactDOM.render(<HelloFromPortal />, portalContainer) }` instead of `{ReactDOM.createPortal(...)}`? I tested it in codesandbox - does not seem to be any different: https://codesandbox.io/s/88p7lwn3l

Comment: @PhilippMunin In addition to the context being saved in portals, events propagate up. Try to add a click listener in the topmost div of `<HelloReact>`, and see that when using `render` clicks from `<HelloFromPortal>` do not propagate up. When using `createPortal`, clicks from inside the portal propagate up to the parent component.

Comment: What about ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer instead of render? it should pass the context, not sure about event

Comment: Dan doesn't recommend it. https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/774591126602911746

Comment: @PhilippMunin I've updated my answer to answer your comment.

Comment: Funny thing about ReactDOM is, it's ideal for dynamically creating things, yet every example shows it doing a trivial `getElementById` in a hello world program. When do you clean up the host element you dynamically created (2nd `createPortal` parameter)? You don't? You are expected to have a static and global thing, it seems.

Comment: Am I supposed to trigger a state change that causes a render that doesn't createPortal, to clean up the host element, then what, `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` on my host? I can't believe nobody shows anything dynamic.

Answer (score 8):

I think we can achieve same feature by creating an external dom node outside 'root' element

```
node = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(node)
ReactDOM.render(<Modal {...props} />,node)
```

Let's say we are creating a modal view, we can create a wrapper for the same

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Modal from './Modal'
let node = null
const ModalWrapper = (props) =>{
    useEffect(()=>{
        node && ReactDOM.render(<Modal {...props} />,node)
    })
    useEffect(()=>{
        node = document.createElement('div')
        document.body.appendChild(node)
        ReactDOM.render(<Modal {...props} />,node)
    },[])
    return(
        <script />
    )
}
```

Here is an example [Create Modal with React Portal and React Hooks from scratch without external library](http://www.recompile.in/2020/01/create-modal-with-react-portal-and.html)

[image: React-modal with portal]

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wondering, here is how I implemented my own custom Portal component in Typescript

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

    const Portal: React.FC<PortalProps> = (props) => {
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(props.children, props.target)
    }

    export interface PortalProps {
        target: Element;
        children: React.ReactNode;
    }

    export default Portal
```

Answer (score 2):

Portals are created by calling the `createPortal` method inside the `render` method of your component.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(this.renderPortal(), this.props.portalEl)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

`renderPortal` should return contents to be rendered inside the portal, while `portalEl` is an external DOM element that will receive the content.

Someone recently twitted that info on portals can be found in [React tests](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a160f3ecfa2fff67d8dec9c22a63300b78d3ad0c/src/renderers/dom/fiber/__tests__/ReactDOMFiber-test.js#L184).

Answer (score 0):

**For example**

```
const Popover = React.memo((props) => {
  
  // your component implementation

  return (
   <div>Hi! I am a Popover in  body!</div>
  );
});


// This allows you to insert a component in the portal when you call the component;
export default function (props) {
  return (
    React.createPortal(<Popover {...props} />, document.body)
  );
}
```