# Meteorjs + React, how to render several elements in Meteor.startup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am trying to declare two different React elements that I would like to render. The both elements are separated elements such as displayed elements (App.jsx) and the customized account system (Login.jsx). But in my test I have the same code in the both jsx file to ensure that the issue is not related to a specific part of them.

I have also created an /imports/startup/client/index.js file (called in the /client/main.js file):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import './accounts-config.js';
import App from '/imports/ui/App.jsx';
import Login from '/imports/ui/Login.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
    render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
    render(<Login />, document.getElementById('login'));
})
```

and the /client/main.html contains the related div tags:

```
...
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="login"></div>
...
```

The issue is that the second render is never displayed (here, the div login) and I observe that only the first render is interpreted.

All the examples that I've found only deals with a single react element. So I wonder how to use several separated react elements like it is in my html file ?

I am newbie in the meteorjs and react world , so maybe I didn't get the right philosophy...

Comment: render `App` and `Login` into a different component. Then render that component inside Meteor.startup().
Something like : 
`render(<NewComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue using only one render in the Meteor.startup(() (in my index.js).
The React doc specifies that only one render can be declared in the Meteor.startup(() (in my index.js).
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

My code is the following:
in my index.js

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
})
```

The trick is that this Super component (App.jsx) has to be used to call all the other components. In my example by calling the Login component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Login />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of React 16 new feature that is portal.

For how to use ReactDOM.createPortal please refer to following link:
[How to use ReactDOM.createPortal() in React 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393642/how-to-use-reactdom-createportal-in-react-16)

Answer (score 0):

I believe because the render() statement has an implicit return statement as well, so since it can only execute and return one, the next render statement isn't executed.